# Laravel save / update many to many relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, relationship

Can anyone help me on how to save many to many relationship? I have tasks, user can have many tasks and task can have many users (many to many), What I want to achieve is that in *update form* admin can assign multiple users to specific task. This is done through html multiple select input

```
name="taskParticipants[]"
```

The catch here is that through the same form (input) you can add/remove users, that's why I have to use sync().
Maybe I should start from the beginning but don't know where to start...

**This is my User model:**

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Task','user_tasks');
}
```

**Task model**

```
public function taskParticipants()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User','user_tasks');
}
```

**TaskController**

```
public function update($task_id)
{
    if (Input::has('taskParticipants'))
    {
        foreach(Input::get('taskParticipants') as $worker)
        {
            $task2 = $task->taskParticipants->toArray();
            $task2 = array_add($task2,$task_id,$worker);
            $task->taskParticipants()->sync(array($task2));
        }
    }
}
```

**This is structure of tables**
    tasks
    id|title|deadline

```
user_tasks
id|task_id|user_id
```

Comment: I've updated my code. 
[link](http://laravel.io/bin/y6jXo)

Comment: `$workers = Input::get('taskParticipants'); $task->taskParticipants()->sync($workers);` and that's all you need, as long as you pass from that form all the users, assigned to the task.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk Thanks, That was magical.

Answer (score 253, accepted):

***tldr;* Use `sync` with 2nd param `false`**

---

Many-to-many relationship is `belongsToMany` on both models:

```
// Task model
public function users()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'user_tasks'); // assuming user_id and task_id as fk
}

// User model
public function tasks()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('Task', 'user_tasks');
}
```

---

In order to add new relation use `attach` or `sync`.

Difference between the two is:

**1** `attach` will add new row on the pivot table without checking if it's already there. It's good when you have additional data linked to that relation, for example:

`User` and `Exam` linked with pivot table `attempts: id, user_id, exam_id, score`

I suppose this is not what you need in your situation:

```
$user->tasks()->getRelatedIds(); // [1,2,3,4,5,6]

$user->tasks()->attach([5,6,7]);
// then
$user->tasks()->getRelatedIds(); // [1,2,3,4,5,6,5,6,7]
```

---

**2** `sync` on the other hand, will either remove all relations and set them up anew:

```
$user->tasks()->getRelatedIds(); // [1,2,3,4,5,6]

$user->tasks()->sync([1,2,3]);
// then
$user->tasks()->getRelatedIds(); // [1,2,3]
```

or it will setup new relations without detaching previous AND without adding duplicates:

```
$user->tasks()->sync([5,6,7,8], false); // 2nd param = detach
// then
$user->tasks()->getRelatedIds(); // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Comment: It'd be nice if that was documented in the main docs rather than the API docs! Rock on. +1.

Comment: I really like second solution with sync and 2nd parameter. 
Like I said in comment bellow, I can't afford not to use detach. 
The story is that admin can assign task to users. He select users from dropdown (multiple), field is participants[]. 
So... :
Step 1: admin assigns task A to three users (your method works, we have 3 records in DB)
Step 2: admin updates task A and adds two users (your method works, we have 5 records in DB) 
Step 3: admin updates task A and removes 1 user (your method fails, we still have 5 users instead of 4) 
[my update method my code](http://laravel.io/bin/21KR1)

Comment: You can simplify your relationship query to just `$this->belongsToMany('User')` if you use name the table alphabetically and singular (so `task_user` instead of `user_tasks`)

Comment: @Rok if you always pass an array of all related users, then use `sync` with detaching, no worries. I suggest using 2nd param set to false whenever you'd like to 'add new task for a user' or 'assign user to a task', when you pass single `id` of the related model.

Comment: Is there any such thing for 'oneToMany' relationship?

Comment: @halkujabra similiar in what way?

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk anything like 'sync'

Comment: @halkujabra just `->relation()->saveMany(array $models)`

Comment: How do you know if sync or attach ran successfully?

Comment: @FabioAntunes `sync` returns an array with `detached`, `attached` and `updated` lists. `attach` doesn't return anything, but in both cases you would get an exception if something unexpected happend in the db calls.

Comment: Awesome @JarekTkaczyk! `getRelatedIds` changed to `allRelatedIds`. Please update your answer for later comers.

Comment: In Laravel 9.X there is now a new method for this: `->syncWithoutDetaching()` which does not require the second `false` parameter.

Answer (score 138):

Here's my notes on how to save and update on all the Eloquent relationships.

in **One to One**:

You have to use **HasOne** on the first model and **BelongsTo** on the second model

to add record on the first model (**HasOne**) use the **save** function

example:    `$post->comments()->save($comment);`

to add record on the second model (**BelongsTo**) use the **associate** function

example:    `$user->account()->associate($account);    $user->save();`

---

in **One to Many**:

You have to use **HasMany** on the first model and **BelongsTo** on the second model

to add record on the first table (**HasMany**) use the **save** or **saveMany** functions

example:    `$post->comments()->saveMany($comments);`

to add record on the second model (**BelongsTo**) use the **associate** function

example:    `$user->account()->associate($account);    $user->save();`

---

in **Many to Many**:

You have to use **BelongsToMany** on the first model and **BelongsToMany** on the second model

to add records on the pivot table use **attach** or **sync** functions

- both functions accepts single ID or array of ID’s
- the difference is attach checks if the record already exist on the pivot table while sync don’t

example: `$user->roles()->attach($roleId);`

---

in **Polymorphic One to Many**:

You have to use **MorphMany** on the main model and **MorphTo** on all the (***able) models

to add records on all the other models use the **save**

example:    `$course->tags()->save($tag);`

the pivot table should have the following columns:

. main model ID

. (***able) ID

. (***able) Type

---

in **Polymorphic Many to Many**:

You have to use **MorphByMany** on the main model and **MorphToMany** on all the (***able) models

to add records on all the other models use the **save** or **saveMany**

example:    `$course->tags()->save($tag);`

example:    `$course->tags()->saveMany([$tag_1, $tag_2, $tag_3]);`

the pivot table should have the following columns:

. main model ID

. (***able) ID

. (***able) Type

---

in **Has Many Through** (shortcut):

You have to use **HasManyThrough** on the first table and have the normal relations on the other 2 tables

this doesn’t work for **ManyToMany** relationships (where there’s a pivot table)

however there’s a nice and easy solution just for that.

---

Here's an article I wrote, inspired by this answer. Important to check it:  https://hackernoon.com/eloquent-relationships-cheat-sheet-5155498c209

Comment: I actually placed this answer when they already had over 40 likes on the correct answer, but yes I know how useful this is for me, glad you like it :)

Comment: how to update one to may relation. u explained how to add . could you please explain the update too? is there a method to update records like `updateMany` something like that? thanks

Answer (score 4):

`syncWithoutDetaching([$id_one, $id_two, $id_three]);` is what you are looking for. Actually it does the exact thing [`sync` with 2nd param `false`] does!

Answer (score 2):

Solved: Use the updateOrInsert(array $attributes, array $values = [])

```
     DB::table('your_pivot_table')->updateOrInsert([
                'col' => $someValue
                

            ],[

                    'otherColumn' => $otherVlaue,
                   
                ]);
            

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sync` function obliterates the exiting relationships and makes your array the entire list of relations. You want `attach` instead to add relations without removing others.

Comment: I can't use attach because I'm using this code inside update method. 
The story is that admin can update task and fill in input participants[] with users that will participate in task. 
So I need to check if it exists and delete (or not to add new record)  it or if it doesn't exist add it.

Answer (score 0):

for those who are searching for adding pivot attributes (the middle table attributes), you can use syncWithPivotValues and it also has the second parameter like this

```
$user->tasks()->syncWithPivotValues($tasksIDs,['day_number' => $day],false);
```