# many-to-many relationship - save data

Tags: php, laravel

I made relationship between `Film` and `Performer` model.

**Films model:**

```
public function Performers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Performer');
}
```

**Performer model:**

```
public function Films()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Films');
}
```

I've created table `film_performer` and relationship works, if I would add data manually.

I have a problem with saving data into `film_performer` after send form.

Into controller I attach it.

```
$film->performers()->attach($request->performers);
```

I don't have any errors. I used `dd($request)` to check array performers and everything is ok

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel save / update many to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702640/laravel-save-update-many-to-many-relationship)

Answer (score 1):

Change `$request->performers` to `$request->performers->pluck('id')` in:

```
$film->performers()->attach($request->performers)
```

The `attach` method expects an array of ids.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

> For convenience, attach and detach also accept arrays of IDs as input:
>
> $user = App\User::find(1);
>
> $user->roles()->detach([1, 2, 3]);
>
> $user->roles()->attach([
>       1 => ['expires' => $expires],
>       2 => ['expires' => $expires]
>   ]);

Comment: It doesn't work. I do this before with tag and it works
$film->tags()->attach($request->tags);