# How to save record in database using belongs to many relation in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have three tables: `restaurant_location`, `cuisine_restaurant_location` and cuisines.

There is a list of all cuisines in my cuisines table. I have all the details of the restaurant in my restaurant_location table. A restaurant can have many cuisines so I made a table cuisine_restaurant_location in which there are two columns cuisine_id and restaurant_id. I have created a belongs to many relation in my restaurant_location model.

**restaurant_location model**

```php
public function cuisines()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Cuisine::class, 'cuisine_restaurant_location', 'restaurant_id', 'cuisine_id');
}
```

I have a form in which all the details of the restaurant along with cuisines is supposed to be added. Right now I am adding all the details of the restaurant. Now the question is how can I insert the cuisines in "cuisine_restaurant_location".

**Controller**

```php
$rest = new restaurant_location;
$rest->name = $request->input('name');
$rest->description = $request->input('desc');
$rest->save();
$cuisine = new cuisine_restaurant_location
$cuisine_lists = $request->input('cuisines');
foreach ($cuisine_lists as $cuisine_list) {
    $cuisine->name = $cuisine_list;
}
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702640/laravel-save-update-many-to-many-relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sync` and `attach` methods, [described in the Many to many section of the eloquent documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships), for that:

```php
$rest->cuisines()->attach([$cuisineIds])
```

Where `cuisineIds` is the list of ids of the cuisines you want to relate.
The difference between `sync` and `attach` is that `sync` will remove all id's not present on the array of ids you are passing.

Comment: I have a list of cuisine ids which i want to insert with the restaurant id. I use this $rest->cuisines()->attach(['cuisine_id'=>$cuisine_ids]); which result the error (`cuisine_id`, `location_id`, `0`, `1`) values (cuisine_id, 30, 1, 2)). ) column not found. can you tell me how to fix this ??

Comment: You should directly insert ids as a plain array, not an key-value array, like: `$cuisineIds = [1,2,3]`

Comment: it is still adding a column 0. Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `cuisine_restaurant_location` (`cuisine_id`, `restaurant_id`, `0`) values (0, 31, 1)).

Comment: Can you dump your `$cuisine_ids` array before attaching and post the result here? If you just want to attach the cuisine with ids 1 and 2 the array should be like `[1, 2]`

Answer (score 0):

Try sync() method:

```
$h = [];
if (isset($input["cuisine_id"])) {
    $h = $input["cuisine_id"];
}
$restaurant_location->cuisines()->sync($h);
```