# How to save manytomany in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to save manyto many in laravel. I have been trying for almost 7 hours. But still can't solve this issue.

Here is custom migration table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('customer', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string("customer_phone", 255);
        });
    }
```

Here is my send_messages migration table:

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('send_messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger("template_id");
            $table->unsignedBigInteger("sender_number_id");
            // $table->unsignedBigInteger("cutomer_id");
            $table->foreign("template_id")->references("id")->on("messagecontent")->onDelete("cascade");
            $table->foreign("sender_number_id")->references("id")->on("sendernumber")->onDelete("cascade");
           // $table->foreign("customer_id")->references("id")->on("customer")->onDelete("cascade");

        });
    }
```

Here is my pivot table:

```
Schema::create('customer_send_message', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->foreignId("send_messages_id")->constrained("send_messages");
    $table->foreignId("customer_id")->constrained("customer");
});
```

Here is CustomerModel

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "customer";

    protected $fillable = [ "customer_phone" ];

    public function sendmessage () {
        return $this->belongsToMany(SendMessage::class, "customer_send_message");
    }

}
```

Here is my SendMessageModel

```
class SendMessage extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "send_messages";

    protected $fillable = [
        "customer_id",
        "template_id",
        "sender_number_id"
    ];

    public function messageContent() {
        return $this->belongsTo(MessageContentModel::class);
    }

    public function senderNumber() {
        return $this->belongsTo(SendNumberModel::class);
    }

    public function customer() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Customer::class, "customer_send_message");
    }

}
```

Here is my controller I am trying to save:

```
    public function send(Request $request) {
        $sendmessage = new SendMessage();

        $sendmessage->template_id = $request->get("template_id");
        $sendmessage->sender_number_id = $request->get("sender_number_id");


        $customers = Customer::find(1);
        $sendmessage->customer()->attach($customers);
        $sendmessage->save();
//        $send->save();
        return redirect("")->with("message", "Sms sent!");
    }
```

I want to get multiple data then I want to save it just like django manytomanyfield. Acutally I was a django developer I recently switched to laravel. I don't know so many things. So Is there any solution for solving this issue? I just want to save.

I am getting an error while saving :

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'send_message_id' in 'field list'

I don't know why I am getting this error!!

Comment: How are you calling/using the relationships to lead to that error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel save / update many to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702640/laravel-save-update-many-to-many-relationship)

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa no its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to laravel's 'convention over configuration' policy, it tends to make some assumptions regarding your column names. If the column names don't match those assumptions, you run into these kind of issues. IIRC, the problem here is that your class name is `SendMessage`, from which Laravel will deduce the foreign key on your pivot table is `send_message_id`, it is however `send_messages_id`.

You should be able to fix this by changing your relation definition in `SendMessage`:

```php
public function customer() {
  return $this->belongsToMany(
    Customer::class, 
    'customer_send_message', 
    'send_messages_id'
  );
}
```

Comment: same error :( can't fix the issue

Comment: I am getting this right now

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'send_messages_id' cannot be null

Comment: Ah, that's because you're calling `$sendmessage->customer()->attach($customers)` before `$sendmessage->save()`. You should first save your model, and then attach it. If you don't save your model first, you don't have an ID and the insert will indeed fail.